# Trouble sorting query by date range followed by other criteria. Union? Concatenate? Looking for ideas

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, sorting, datetime

In my Android SQLite database, I have a column that is a datetime in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM. I want a query (or a cursor, actually) that will give me all of the rows in, let's say May 2015. The sorting is where I'm getting stuck. I want my results broken down first by week, then for each week a sort based on other columns.

Right now I'm just sorting by the datetime column, followed by the other columns. Eg: `ORDER BY t.TASKS_DATETIME ASC, s.STATUSES_RANK ASC, t.TASKS_CATEGORY`. But basically every row has a unique value for datetime (even though I don't care about hours and minutes in this case) so no other sorting happens and the end result is not very user friendly. The sort order is really important for the user to look at and understand this data.

I thought about doing a separate select statement for each of the weeks, then doing a `UNION ALL` to get the month data. But you can't use the `ORDER BY` clause with a `UNION`, because it sorts the whole union, not just the individual select statements inside. Not to mention, it's pretty ugly.

I thought maybe I could do it on the Android/Java side and concatenate multiple Cursor objects. But I can't find any way to do that. Does anyone here know a way? I've been away from Java for a few years and was never that intimate with the language to start.

I thought maybe I could use the SQLite date functions  [https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html ] in some way. Maybe add a new column in my select that has the week of year. Then I could sort by that new column, followed by the other sort criteria that I want. Or maybe there is a way to put a range (or simplified datetime) into the `ORDER BY` clause. But this is pushing the boundaries of my SQLite skills. Does this seem possible? FYI, on the Android/Java side, I convert this datetime String to a GregorianCalendar.

**I'm hoping someone smarter than me on here can point me in a good direction! None of these options seems great and I can't think of any others.**

If I can't figure out anything else, I'll go with the `UNION` option. And add a "week_of_year" column to each select statement inside to identify that week, as suggested by other union/sorting questions here. Then sort by that "week_of_year" column, followed by my other sort criteria. I've started working on this. But I took a break to ask for better ideas here, cause my gut says there has to be a better way. But maybe not :)

---

As additional background, that I don't think is relevant, but just in case...

This scary query is being used in a StickyHeaderList [https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders ], where the weeks are the headers. If I don't sort first by datetime, the headers/weeks end up out of order. Sometimes they even duplicate.

I will probably at some point write my own alternative or alter this StickyHeaderList code, perhaps something that takes a cursor for each week/header rather than just one for the whole month. I can deal with dates easier in Java then SQL. But I don't have the resources for that today. The biggest headache, I imagine, will be having the multiple-select CAB menu allow me to select across different lists. If you happen to know an easy work around for that, maybe I will just do that and accept the major rework over figuring out this query.

---

**UPDATE: It works!**

Many thanks to @CL for giving me the answer. For posterity and clarity, here are some notes.

The correct answer is:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY strftime('%Y%W', t.TASKS_DATETIME),
     s.STATUSES_RANK,
     t.TASKS_CATEGORY
```

As noted, weeks are finicky things. I need to also account for users who have weeks that start on different days of the week. Note, the SQLite default is to start the ween on *Monday* (not Sunday). Also, the keyword is `day` not `days` for accounting for that offset. Also, the offset should be made *to the right* of the datetime.

This left me with:

```
 "ORDER BY strftime('%Y %W', t." + TASKS_SCHED_DATETIME + weekOffset + ")," + 
     "s." + STATUSES_RANK + " ASC, " +
     "t." + TASKS_CATEGORY + " DESC "
```

Which in the end becomes: `ORDER BY strftime('%Y %W', t.task_sched_datetime, '+5 day' ),  s.status_rank ASC, t.tasks_category DESC`

`weekOffset` is defined in a little helper function:

```
private String calculateWeekOfset() {
    int wkStart = App.getWeekStart();
    int offset = 9 - wkStart; // Calendar.MONDAY == 2
    return ", '+" + Integer.toString(offset)+ " day' ";
}
```

I think that's all. Thanks again!

Comment: "I thought maybe I could do it on the Android/Java side and concatenate multiple Cursor objects. But I can't find any way to do that. Does anyone here know a way?" -- [`CursorJoiner` kinda does this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html). "I want my results broken down first by week" -- is May 1-7 2015 a week? Or is April 26-May 2 a week? IOW, are these Sun-to-Sat calendar weeks, or simply seven-day increments from the start of the month?

Comment: @Kaitlyn Hanrahan, i guess i get what you are trying to do, but, can you bring some kind of your code to understand your problem, i get a differente ideas about it, i have some problems on the db like you, you have 2 or more tables? just to get it right :)

Comment: @CommonsWare To define a week, I take local standards for default settings (start Sun or Mon) then allow changes in Preferences. On the Java side, I use `GregorianCalendar`, `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR`, and `GregorianCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek()` to track weeks. 

If I can ask, do you have any thoughts on CL's answer? I've never used `strftime()` and the documentation doesn't talk about using it in this way, that I see. 

PS- I subscribe to "The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development". I love the content and the always-up-to-date structure. I recommend it whenever asked.

Comment: "do you have any thoughts on CL's answer?" -- I think that if it works and performs adequately for you, go with it. I was kinda wandering down this direction with my question, though CL is several steps ahead of where I was. And thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract fields from a timestamp, use the [strftime function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
In this case, you need the week of the year, and the year itself to make dates in different years unique:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY strftime('%Y%W', t.TASKS_DATETIME),
         s.STATUSES_RANK,
         t.TASKS_CATEGORY
```

If you do not want to start a week on a Monday, add or subtract the appropriate number of days:

```
... strftime('%Y%W', t.TASKS_DATETIME, '+1 days'), ...
```

Comment: This is doing something, but I don't understand what. These are my datetimes as returned after adding your suggestion. It seems to be grouping by day but not in order. Within each date cluster the order (secondary sort columns) is correct. I'm testing on a Sun-started week, so not shifting `+1 days` for now. Thoughts? Results:
2015-04-26 17:10
2015-04-26 21:30
2015-04-26 22:56
2015-04-26 17:08
2015-04-26 17:08
2015-04-26 21:30
2015-04-26 22:56
2015-05-03 21:30
2015-04-29 17:08
2015-05-02 18:10
2015-04-27 22:56
2015-04-27 17:08
2015-04-28 21:30
2015-04-28 17:08
2015-04-27 18:10
2015-05-08 17:57

Comment: You wanted sorting by week, and this is sorted by week. The order inside a week is determined by the two other columns, and where those are identical, is random. Are you saying that you *do* want to sort by the day/time?

Comment: Ah ha! Yes it works! I had to stare at the data a bit to figure it all out. I really appreciate your help! This was a very specific-to-me problem that probably won't help many other people, but you saved me!